# In Spring4D how to register multiple auto factories for same interface

Tags: delphi, spring4d

I want to provide the constructor arguments to the following class via the container but am unable to find a way of registering the multiple auto factories.

```
TItemFactory = class(TInterfacedObject, IItemFactory)
private
  fFactories: TArray<Func<IHost,IItem>>;
protected
  function CreateInstance(Host: IHost): TArray<IItem>;
public
  constructor Create(Factories: TArray<Func<IHost,IItem>>);
end;
```

If I wanted to have multiple types of items I could register them as

```
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<IItem,TItem1>('Item1');
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<IItem,TItem2>('Item2');
```

If I only had one type of item I could easily

```
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<IItem,TItem1>;
GlobalContainer.RegisterFactory<Func<IHost,IItem>>;
```

But I can see there is no point in naming multiple auto factories as they only reference IItem and not TItem1 or TItem2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, look at the parameters of `RegisterFactory`, there are two overloads where you can specify the `resolvedServiceName`.

```
GlobalContainer.RegisterFactory<Func<IHost, IItem>>('ItemFactory1', 'Item1');
GlobalContainer.RegisterFactory<Func<IHost, IItem>>('ItemFactory2', 'Item2');
```